# Accessing Frame object from MainWindow for navigation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, navigation

I am building an application where I have to navigate between few pages. Here is how I am trying to set it up. I want this navigation to work through the buttons that I have on my pages without displaying left/right arrow navigation buttons at the top. I have my main window setup as follows where all I have is a Frame within a DockPanel

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

In this constructor, I load my first page.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _mainFrame.Navigate(new Page1());
        }
    }
```

Here is how  my page1 is setup.

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
Title="Page1">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
        <RowDefinition  />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0">This is Page 1</Label>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Next" Click="Next_Click" />

</Grid>
```

When user click on Next button, I want to take to Page2. So I probably want something like as follows in next button handler.

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   _mainFrame.Navigate(new Page2());
}
```

I am not sure how to get reference to this !mainFrame object. Can you please suggest any better ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try putting the StartupUri in your main window for a default page.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        StartupUri="Page1.xaml">
    <DockPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And then inside your Page1.xaml add in the following NavigationUri to get to the next/previous page.

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
Title="Page1">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
        <RowDefinition  />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0">This is Page 1</Label>
    <!-- this should replace your button navigation -->
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="Page2.xaml">
       Navigate to Another Page
    </Hyperlink>

</Grid>
```

The hyperlink will automatically look to either the parent or indirect parent to find the Navigation Host (the Frame).

Comment: Got two error when trying to do above. 1. The property 'StartupUri' was not found in type 'Window'. 2. A value of type 'Hyperlink' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.

Comment: Are you wanting this to be in a web browser?